# How to get positions of individual lines in a html text node

Tags: javascript, html

Not sure how to word this question. What I want to do is get the positions of individual lines in an HTML text node.

For example, in this image, each blue box is a `span` with some styling and padding. So the blue box with the text "test 3 testing hello test test test!" is a single `span` that wraps onto the next line and it's HTML looks like this:

```
<span>test 3 testing hello test test test!</span>
```

[image]

**How can I get the client top, left, width, and height for each of the two lines of text? That is, I'd like all the size/position information for just the "test 3 testing hello test" part of the line, as well as the size/position information for the "test test!" line. Relative to either the page or the parent div.** If I call `getBoundingClientRect()` on the `span` itself, it gives me none of that information, just the combination of the first and second line, and as far as I can tell the text is not broken up into smaller nodes for me to iterate over in JS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer after I gave up on this problem several months ago.

Apparently, you can call `getBoundingClientRect()` on a `Range`. This will give you the bounding rect of the selected text.

If greater detail is needed, down the the individual lines of the text, then you should call `getClientRects()` on the `Range`, which will return a rect for each line of text in the selected range.

```js
  const el = document.querySelector("#my-element");
  const range = document.createRange();
  range.setStart(el, 0);
  range.setEnd(el, 200);

  // A single rect for the entire range
  const rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();

  // An array of rects for each line of the range
  const rects = range.getClientRects();
```

Although it's considered an experimental API by MDN, both functions are supported by all major browsers:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/getBoundingClientRect
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/getClientRects

Answer (score 0):

The method `elem.getBoundingClientRect()` returns window coordinates for a minimal rectangle that encloses elem as an object of built-in DOMRect class.

**Main DOMRect properties:**

`x/y` – X/Y-coordinates of the rectangle origin relative to window,
`width/height` – width/height of the rectangle (can be negative).
Additionally, there are derived properties:

`top/bottom` – Y-coordinate for the top/bottom rectangle edge,
`left/right` – X-coordinate for the left/right rectangle edge.

**Document coordinates:**

```
// get document coordinates of the element
function getCoords(elem) {
  let box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();

  return {
    top: box.top + window.pageYOffset,
    right: box.right + window.pageXOffset,
    bottom: box.bottom + window.pageYOffset,
    left: box.left + window.pageXOffset
  };
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I understand that, but the question is much more complicated. I need the same information, top right bottom and left, for each line of text inside the span.

Comment: @JaeKwak I think you can't do that with a basic solution, you can do that either with a complicated one or you just need to divide text inside span into other elements.